# macbook pro stuck in boot loop - recovery mode and safe mode not working

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, unix, mojave

I have a macbook pro 2015 (8gb ram, running macOS mojave) stuck in the loading screen with the apple logo and the loading bar 100% completed.

- I tried leaving it for long periods of time.
- Resetting the PRAM and SMC didn't help.
- The machine wont go into safe mode using the shift button.
- It also won't go into recovery mode using command+R.
- Internet recovery also does not work either. After the globe finishes loading in internet recovery, it goes back to the boot up screen with the apple logo and stays stuck there at 100%.
- when I run the AHT (Apple Diagnostics) by holding down the d button, the test runs smoothly and exits with the message "no issues found". When I click "Get Started" it starts booting the os and freezes again in the logo screen.
- I successfully entered the MacOS Utilities Screen by using a bootable USB drive with macOS mojave on it, but here's what happened

  - The Disk Utility was unable to load any drives or partitions, it only displayed a spinner and pretty much hangs on startup. However the machine didn't hang, I could still exit the Disk Utility. Here's a link with an image of the disk utility: https://m.imgur.com/gallery/MxfSna8
  - When I click "Install macOS" nothing happens
  - In the terminal, when I `cd` into the Volume "Macintosh HD", then `ls`, the terminal process hangs.

    - What's odd is that in single-user-mode, `ls`ing around the internal ssd was not a problem.
- I ran fsck from the single-user-mode, it exits with the message:
  `The  volume /dev/rdisk1s1 appears to be OK.` I put a link below of a photo showing the console output of the fsck process.
- When I use the exit command to exit single-user-mode the machine hangs. I put a link below with a photo showing the console output following the exit command.

Log output in single-user-mode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlldd.jpg

Log output when starting in verbose mode:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXpIR.jpg

Result after booting into AHT:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0r7N.jpg

Below i go into details about what I was doing prior to this issue:

- I ran 8 consecutive node.js processes, to write about 11 GB of randomly generated data to an external SSD.
- each processes was given about 8gb of ram with the flag `--max-old-space-size=8000` (the machine itself only has 8GBs of ram, and there's usually about 3GBs that are always occupied)
- each process was pretty much writing to a csv file using a for loop and a node fs write stream
- each processes was followed by a `killall -kill node`
- after the processes were done the os started doing unexpectable things so I shut it down. (unexpectable things such as the desktop background image was changed, and all terminals would restart every time I put the macbook to sleep).
- after shutting it down, when I turned it back on the external ssd was still connected, so I unplugged it right before the apple logo appeared, that's when it hanged.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: it is recommend to repeat the `fsck` multiple times (10x) since not every scan caches all problems.

Comment: stupid question I know, but do you have USB with OSX on it

Comment: according to the log you provided your disk and Mojave are compromised (kaput). Using external boot disk you can try to repair that. For example the APFS should be some 50 GB or more and yours is 9MB ? that would explain that it can not find multiple files that it needs to proceed.

Comment: @Buscar웃 so you would say that booting it from an external drive (that has the OS on it) is the only solution at this point? i'm also not sure i quite understand how the APFS and mojave were compromised? if you don't mind explaining. And to answer the question, unfortunately I do not currently have a usb with OSX on it.

Comment: just look at your log, it is missing Mojave files and the APFS disk size is way to small. How that happened I do not know.

Comment: @Buscar웃 ah i see, thanks. Shouldn't internet recovery work at least?

Comment: It should but it is located on your disk in the recovery portion, since you can get there as you say with Command (⌘) – Option (⌥) – R ?

Comment: Looking at your logs, there doesn't appear to be an issue that `fsck` is going to address.  Additionally, given that you're having the same issue booting into Internet Recovery (which doesn't use your local storage at all) points to a bigger issue.  Start with [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.

Comment: @Buscar웃 yeah that's not working for some reason.

Comment: @Allan thank you for the help. I just tried that and the AHT ended with the message "No issues found", then I press "Get Started" it goes back to the boot screen with the logo and hangs. I updated the post with a link to the exit message i got from the AHT process.

Comment: @Allan moreover, i don't seem to be getting the ordinary AHT menu options like "perform extended testing". I only get a language menu, then a loading bar, then it completes testing in less than a minue with the message "no issues found."

Comment: I don't know if you have the tools available, but if you do, try and remove the SSD from the logic board and run Internet Recovery again.  This will help determine if you're having an issue with the internal SSD.

Comment: I agree with @Allan on what I'd try next, assuming you feel comfortable in doing that. Also, to answer your question about why you're not getting the *normal* AHT menu, it's because your MBP doesn't use AHT. All Macs launched since June 2013 use Apple Diagnostics instead and there's no *menu* as such, nor an *extended testing* option.

Comment: As it says you have no Hardware problem but your Mojave and Recovery portions are corrupted. The regular internal Recovery does sit on your SSD  as 'APFS Volume Recovery  515.0 MB   disk1s3' and I would feel more comfortable getting a USB stick then doing surgery on the Mac. The fsck did not find anything because your SSD is fine physically but what is on it is not.

Comment: @Monomeeth and @ Allan Since i never opened a mac I don't feel very comfortable doing that but if all fails I will give that a go. However, if the SSD is bad how come i can still see all my files perfectly intact using vim in single-user-mode?

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes this is what I am attempting now, I will try to boot it up from a bootable usb with macOS on it. I will definitely exhaust all my options before I even think about touching hardware.

Comment: I would agree to try some non invasive methods before performing major surgery, while as you say the patient might just have a flu.

Comment: @Buscar웃 using a bootable USB didn't work. I updated the post with what happened. The macOS utility loads up successfully, but none of the options work. Nothing happens when I click "install macOS", the Disk Utility hangs when I start it, and the terminal hangs when I `ls` in "Macintosh HD"

Comment: can we see the Disk Utility screen form the USB. It should have loaded all drivers that it needs to work.

Comment: @Buscar웃 here's the Disk Utility screen when I open it: https://m.imgur.com/gallery/MxfSna8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using a bootable Ubuntu usb to boot my system, and choosing the option for formatting the SSD. Then after installing Ubuntu I was able to use a bootable MacOS usb drive to reinstall MacOS Mojave successfully.
As mentioned above, absolutely nothing was working including the disk utility, internet recovery, or using a bootable MacOS USB drive. Everything was causing the system to freeze.

Answer (score 0):

@Imael Oooo that is serious. I have had this problem with 10.12, which I believe stemmed from I installed an old Epsilon print driver and the kext file reaped havoc, causing exactly the error you described.

To resolve this I booted into the start-up/recovery drive, (turn the machine on and hit "Alt") and opened Terminal. I then went to the two system directories which held .kext files (I forget them at present) and dumped the .kext file into a temporary folder (so the system couldn't find them). It then booted up fine.

Happy to supply the full details if required, it could have been an issue with earlier OS, because OS 10.14 is quite different.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Michael. The terminal didn't work either, when I would open the terminal in the recovery/utilities mode the system would freeze up once I `ls`. Nonetheless I already posted how I solved this above, it was by formatting the ssd completely with an external drive

Comment: Okay, if terminal freezes it is not a system conflict with the .kext files. .. there is "single user mode", but I've never accessed it.

Comment: Single User Mode worked perfectly as read only (for viewing the folders and files) but nothing more. I was unable to write to disk or perform any changes